# Django model serialization problem with default fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

Inside of my app model, I use **IntegerRangeField** fields:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField
from django.contrib.postgres.validators import RangeMinValueValidator, RangeMaxValueValidator
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange


class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    field = IntegerRangeField(default=NumericRange(400, 600), validators=[
        RangeMinValueValidator(1),
        RangeMaxValueValidator(1000)
    ])
    ...
```

---

The "**default**" attributes are used in the admin panel UI only, and are not  needed anywhere else.

If I add them after migration, they work smoothly. However, if I add them before I run makemigrations, I get this message:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: NumericRange(400, 600, '[)') There are
>   some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.

I don't even want the default values to be saved to my PostgreSQL database, I just want to not have to remove and bring them back every time I run makemigrations.

Any ideas?

(Didn't work: a custom object with "lower" and "higher" attributes, a single integer, a string, a tuple)

Python: 3.6.6, Django: 2.1.2, PostgreSQL: 11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move default value calculation into separate function:

```
def get_default_range():
    return NumericRange(400, 600)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field = IntegerRangeField(default=get_default_range, validators=[
        RangeMinValueValidator(1),
        RangeMaxValueValidator(1000)
    ])
```

In this case migration was successfully generated:

```
   operations = [
       migrations.AddField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='field',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ranges.IntegerRangeField(
                default=play.models.get_default_range,
                validators=[django.contrib.postgres.validators.RangeMinValueValidator(1),
                            django.contrib.postgres.validators.RangeMaxValueValidator(1000)]),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you're right, a migration was created, but it just moves the problem elsewhere: when you try to access it you get **AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'lower'**

Comment: @ozz Ok, I see that this does not work. What about simple tuple, like `default=(400, 600)` What errors do you have in this case?

Comment: @ozz As I see in docs you need to use from `psycopg2.extras.NumericRange` only if it's used to filter the model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-range-fields But defining defaults as a tuple is generally ok

Comment: I get the same error: **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'**. I've scanned through the docs, no solution

Comment: @ozz When exactly do you have this error? When running `makemigrations` command or ...? Can you post full stacktrace please

Comment: The error happens when I try to access it in the admin panel. Makemigrations passes cleanly, but it's impossible to use to the model in the admin panel.
Here's the stack trace: https://pastebin.com/0uhEvmBp

Comment: To be more precise, the error happens when I try to create a new instance of the containing model

Comment: @ozz Full traceback would help. It seems that somewhere filtering happens. Because `x = MyModel(); x.field = (100, 200); x.save()` works fine for me. (migrated my table with default tuple too)

Comment: I can migrate my table with a tuple too, but I can't add a new instance in the admin panel. Can you? Here's the traceback: https://pastebin.com/UWViwwBU

Comment: @ozz Yes, I had the same problem when tried to create new model instance(especially in django Range widget code, this is very strange). I've fixed this. But it's a hacky way, I won't advise to use this hack. But it seems that I've fixed it in another way. See updated answer. You'll need to re-run your migrations again :)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much anyways :) I tried your solution, but keep on getting the following error when running makemigrations: **ValueError: Cannot serialize: NumericRange(400, 600, '[)')**.
Stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/dbWhv45K

Comment: @ozz Very strange. I do not have this error anymore. Here's my setup:
https://pastebin.com/SQTjEm5m 
if that doesn't work for you, then I give up =\

Comment: Do you mind telling why it solves it and how did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** I should point out that the original question was 2 years old, but at least in django 3.1, their is a serializer that you must register separately.

You need to register the serializer that is provided by django.

```py
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange
from django.contrib.postgres.serializers import RangeSerializer
from django.db.migrations.writer import MigrationWriter

MigrationWriter.register_serializer(NumericRange, RangeSerializer)
```

This piece was not in the documentation, but then you can add your defaults as you'd expect:

```py
class AgeDivision(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    age_range = fields.IntegerRangeField(
        unique=True, blank=True, default=NumericRange(None, None))
```

as for where to put this, it just needs to go along side any module that is only loaded once. The documentation didn't specify where to put custom serializers (as least that I could find), but I'd say put them in the `migrations/__init__.py` file for any app that requires the serializer. here's the documentation on migration serialization: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#custom-serializers

Comment: FYI, I put the registration in models.py. Not saying that's great, but it's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using the string representation of the range:

```
IntegerRangeField(default='[400, 600]')
```

django==3.0.5
psycopg2==2.8.5