# Django 2.2 cannot serialize default values once migration has been done

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a model which is refered to as a foreignkey with on_delete set to SET_DEFAULT. Because of that, I need to provide this model with a default item. I created a static method which does just that.

```
class ScheduleChoice(models.Model):
    """
    This model allows users to define crontab schedules.
    """
    label = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Label", unique=True)
    job_schedule = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        default="0 0 * * *", verbose_name="Crontab"
    )

    @staticmethod
    def get_default_schedule_choice():
        """
        Because some models rely on ScheduleChoice and need a default value,
        we need to give them a default ScheduleChoice.
        """
        try:
            choice = ScheduleChoice.objects.get_or_create(
                label="Every minute",
                job_schedule="* * * * *"
            )
        except ProgrammingError:
            choice = None
        return choice

    @classmethod
    def get_choice_count(cls):
        """
        Returns how many schedule choices have been defined.
        """
        return len(cls.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "schedule choice"
        verbose_name_plural = "schedule choices"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label


class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    """
    Model using ScheduleChoices.
    """
    job_schedule = models.ForeignKey(
        "ScheduleChoice",
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
        default=ScheduleChoice.get_default_schedule_choice(),
        verbose_name="Schedule"
    )
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="activated")
```

I am able to run makemigrations and migrate without issue.

My problem starts when I modifiy my models and try to use makemigrations again in order to update the migrations files. I get the error :

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: <ScheduleChoice: Every minute>
> There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
> For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing

I tried to apply [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154105/django-model-serialization-problem-with-default-fields), but it didn't help. Why does Django need to serialize my default value ? Why does it only do so after the first migration has successfully ended ?

I can always use reset_db and do my migration, but it is not acceptable in my production environment.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django needs to serialize your models to make migration files for them. Hence it also needs to serialize most of the attributes you set on the model fields (`default` included). Currently you define a method and directly call that instead of providing the method as the default, also your method returns a tuple with `ScheduleChoice` and a boolean.

Django can serialize booleans but not the model instance (for the migration) hence you get an error, not to mention the tuple would have caused an error anyway. You should **not** call the method and instead just pass the method as the default, also instead of returning the instance return only the `pk`, also ideally this method should simply be a function:

```
class ScheduleChoice(models.Model):
    """
    This model allows users to define crontab schedules.
    """
    label = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Label", unique=True)
    job_schedule = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        default="0 0 * * *", verbose_name="Crontab"
    )
    
    @classmethod
    def get_choice_count(cls):
        """
        Returns how many schedule choices have been defined.
        """
        return len(cls.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "schedule choice"
        verbose_name_plural = "schedule choices"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label


def get_default_schedule_choice():
    choice, _created = ScheduleChoice.objects.get_or_create(
        label="Every minute",
        job_schedule="* * * * *"
    )
    # Why would programming error occur?
    return choice.pk # Return the pk

class MyOtherModel(models.Model):
    """
    Model using ScheduleChoices.
    """
    job_schedule = models.ForeignKey(
        "ScheduleChoice",
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
        default=get_default_schedule_choice, # Don't call the function, only pass it
        verbose_name="Schedule"
    )
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="activated")
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct, thanks. Why should it be a function though ?

Comment: @PleaseHelp because 1) It does not need to be a method really. 2) Some older versions of Django may not be able to serialize it if it is a method.